# iOS. Get stack traces of the UI thread, but do it from a different thread

Tags: ios, stack-trace

Now I use this code for getting stack trace:

```
NSArray * stack = [NSThread callStackSymbols];
```

But this code return stack from current tread.

How I can get stack traces of the UI thread, but do it from a different thread?

It necessary in order to find the code which blocks the UI thread.
Or which other way to find the code which blocks the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

**callStackSymbols** is called for the current thread.
[image]

> Or which other way to find the code which blocks the UI thread?
>   Check this link for useful tips
>   https://medium.com/@mandrigin/ios-app-performance-instruments-beyond-48fe7b7cdf2#.xdwqw7jwd